# How do you manage your ignores?

Tags: git, mercurial, gitignore, hgignore

In order to stop writing my `.hgignore` for every new repository; I decided to create a separate repository for my `hgignores` which currently looks like:

```
hgignores    
├── cpp
├── eclipse
├── intellij
├── java
├── latex
├── linux
├── netbeans
├── osx
├── python
└── textmate
```

Now for each repository, I am pasting the relevant ignores.

For example:

```
$ cat hgignores/latex hgignores/osx hgignores/textmate >> [repo]/.hgignore
```

This makes me wonder, if in the future I happen to have forgotten a flag for an ignore file for `cpp` (for example), I will have to edit `hgignores/cpp` and eventually make changes in every `cpp` repository I have AGAIN!

I think I am moving to a right direction by creating a unified repo for ignores, but I maybe missing few tips here and there.

Would love to hear some suggestions; or insights into how you get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Mercurial's repo's `hgrc` to [point to ignore files](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#ui) outside of the repository:

```
[ui]
ignore = /path/to/ignorefile
ignore.cpp = /path/to/cppignorefile
```

You can also do this in your global `hgrc`/`Mercurial.ini`, but that's simply something to keep in mind if you need it someday.

*Of course, this section would have to be re-added to new clones of a repo, since the `hgrc` is not cloned.*

Answer (score 3):

I tend to put all the ignore patterns regarding my personal tools in my global ignore file ([git](http://help.github.com/ignore-files/#global_gitignore), [mercurial](http://blog.djmatty.com/?p=380)): text editor, operating system, etc. Other people working on the project are not concerned by these, so I keep them out of the projects' ignore files.
That's a few ignore patterns you won't have to manage on each project.

Regarding project specific ignores, having template files seems good enough. The patterns needed per language won't change frequently (probably never for most of them). You can still write a small script in your ignores repository to update your ignore file. It would import missing patterns only.

Comment: I use templates for version controlled visual studio solutions (hg only). The .hgignore is tracked by mercurial, and contains rules for the non-source non-automatically generated files. Especially handy when you make COM objects via ATL projects.